# Arduino-Pyserial communication on Python 3, Windows machine: Pyserial.write() doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: serial, softwareserial, python

I've recently gotten my hands on an Arduino (or rather a Genuino, but the overall architecture should be the same) UNO. I'm now using that Arduino to test how data is transmitted from a USB to Serial Connector to the Arduino.

I've already verified that data transmission from Arduino to the PC is possible, by using hTerm and PySerial. However, whenever I send data from Pyserial or hTerm, it doesn't show up in the Arduino serial terminal. Also, I'm using SoftwareSerial to set up a secondary serial terminal to see what the Arduino receives. (I'm using the standard serial port to send data to the terminal, and the SoftwareSerial Port to connect to the USB to Serial Connector.)

Here's my code so far:

Python side:

```python
import serial
import time
import sys
import struct
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=0)
time.sleep(10)
while 1:
    print(ser.write(struct.pack('>B', 0)))
    time.sleep(2)
    print(1)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

The Arduino side looks like this, and is essentially the default example:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SoftwareSerialExample

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  if (Serial) {
    Serial.end();
  }
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }

  Serial.println("Godnight moon!");

  mySerial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.println("Hello, world?");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  mySerial.listen();
  if (mySerial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.println("Hello User");
    Serial.println(mySerial.read());
  }
}
```

The Terminal never prints "Hello User". Also, no other signals are being printed. By removing the if-condition, I get a whole lot of "Hello User" and "-1" in the Arduino IDE serial monitor.

Concerning my setup:

I've got an USB to Serial converter, which is connected as "COM3". On the other side, I have an Arduino UNO which is connected via USB to the same computer. The TX pin of the converter is connected to the RX pin of the Arduino and vice versa. Also, Ground is connected to Ground. Furthermore, I use Jupyter/IPython notebook to run my Python script, and the default Arduino IDE to compile programs for my Arduino. In the case there I received data from the Arduino, I used the script specified in the URL provided, which is very similar to the one I'm already showing here. Also, `ser.write()` is replaced by `ser.read(1)`, so that it reads one byte at a time. My system is Windows 7 (64 Bit).

Edit: Here is an established connection between hTerm (a serial terminal) and the Python script while using com0com as a port emulator.
[image: A successful communication between the Python script and hTerm]

Comment: What are you using to connect to the SoftwareSerial pins?

Comment: Some cables which came with the Genuino starter kit. RX is connected to TX and TX to RX (USB-Serial to Arduino), and ground to ground

Comment: "Some cables" isn't very descriptive. Which TX and RX pins are you connecting to?

Comment: Oh, ok. Well, I'm connecting to Pin 10 (RX) and Pin 11 (TX). Or do you mean how I connect on the other end?

Comment: OK, that makes more sense to me now.

Comment: A diagram of your setup would add a lot of clarity to your question. You checked that the USB-Serial port is COM3? What does the Python shell display when you run the script? To be clear, you connected the RX of the USB-Serial adapter to Arduino pin 11, and its TX to Arduino pin 10? Remove the 'timeout' argument in the 'ser' instantiation in the Python script and try it again.

Comment: I updated the description. And that's correct, COM3 is the port that's assigned to the USB-Serial converter. And Pin 10 (RX) is connected to TX at the USB side, while PIN 11 (TX) is connected to the RX at the USB side. Also, I've already received data from the Arduino, so I don't think it's a problem with the setup. I've also switched around the connection cables, but that doesn't solve it either

Comment: Does it work if you use the builtin hardware serial port of arduino? That way we could try to see if the problem is in the python part or the arduino part.

Comment: Ok, so I used hTerm for this, since this is probably better for debugging right now. When I send a signal from the Arduino Terminal to the Arduino via Serial(Works for both cases, virtual and builtin hardware serial port (Pin 0 (RX) and Pin 1 (TX), right?)), I get an answer in the seperate hTerm window. hTerm is connected to the USB-Serial Converter (COM7). However, if I'm sending data from hTerm or the ipython script to the Arduino, it doesn't respond. (The Arduino IDE terminal and hTerm show nothing). So, my best guess is that the USB-Serial Converter is broken...

Comment: @user25642 - Has the COM port changed number or have I misunderstood.  You program says COM3 yet you are connecting hTerm to COM7.

Comment: Well, I have two USB-Serial Converters, and I just tried them both. Sorry if that was confusing. And they both don't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

What do you think should come out?

I'm no expert with Python but you seem to be using struct pack, which I think prepends a number of bytes to the data to generate a 4 byte word.  You are using NULL, 0 to pack the structure.  When Serial.println() encounter a NULL it will assume that is the end of the string.  So you seem to be printing a zero byte string.

Oh and Serial.read() only reads one byte of data, so there is an issue with that too. I suspect that the write call has a similar issue, you normally need to supply a size parameter because its binary data.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The struct pack has a syntax as follows: 
The ">B" stands for a little endian byte that's gonna be packed, while the 0 is just an int that's packed into the byte. If I print it out, I get b'\x00' , which means that it's just an empty Byte. Is that what you meant with NULL, or is that another parameter?

Comment: And yes, I know that Serial.read(1) reads only one Byte at a time. That was just for testing purposes, as I was sending only one byte at a time. (To see if the connection works at all)

The pySerialAPI (http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html)
states that write only takes one argument, the data. For python 3 it has to be formatted, which is why I'm using the struct package. For a 4 byte word, I would need to use something like ">BBBB", since a single B is just one byte. 
I hope that clarifies what the code does a bit more :)

Comment: Generally, the struct package is used to format variables in python to certain standards. The problem is that a python int only takes up as much space as needed, so it will have a varying length, depending on the size of the number.

Comment: A variable length int, what a silly language :)  Yes thanks that clarifies a lot.  By NULL I do mean 0x00, so if that what you are getting its working.  If you print that as a string then it will seem like it is doing nothing.  Can you write (0x42) rather than packing it, you should get 0x42 on the Arduino or 'B'.

Comment: Ok, so I just used the pack-function to pack b"B" (Which is the bytes representation of a B. Python 3 is Unicode, so that should work) and send it instead of a 0. The Arduino still doesn't display anything.

Comment: Ok, so I c an send data from my python script to hTerm with virtual ports (I'm using com0com). I can also send data from hTerm to my script. But if I connect two USB-Serial Converters to each other, and connect one to hTerm and the other one to the python script, they don't communicate. So now I'll check the drivers and such for the USB-Serial Converters. (Even though they still blink up if they send something)

Comment: Don't use pack() that's what is causing the problem.  You are sending 0x00000043 which is Null, Null, Null B.  When the Arduino reads one byte it see Null, which means it prints nothing.  You need to send the single byte 0x43.  If you want or need to send a word then send 0x43000000.  This way it should work.  
USB <-> Serial <-> Serial <-> USB will not work unless Serial <-> Serial has the RX and TX lines crossed over.  You don't have these lines crossed over because you can use both convertors to talk to the Arduino.

Comment: Can I ask why you are under the impression that pack() is making a 4 byte  number? If I use ">c", I'm packing the string to be its 1 byte character representation. I've checked that with the terminal. Only that one byte arrives, nothing else (I will also try to attach a screenshot of it in my question). And I'm not quite sure what you mean with "crossed over." I connected the TX of Serial-USB to the RX of the other Serial-USB, and vice versa. Is that what you were suggesting?

Comment: I noticed the NULL thing but I assumed Serial.println() would display '0', as though you ran Serial.println(0).

Comment: @user25642 - I was guessing what pack did, so thanks for correcting me.  Yes by "crossed over" I mean tx to rx and rx to tx.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your python code, do you see the things you are sending on the screen there?

I think you need to be calling  ser.open().